# Debugging asset pipeline approach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I've got a Rails app which uses the **twitter-bootstrap-rails** gem to provide Bootstrap resources. I was having a difficult time trying to add **jquery ui**, but that's not my question. When trying to get **jquery ui** working, I added and removed numerous gems and updated files driving the asset pipeline.

Now it seems I have damaged the Rails/Bootstrap javascripts, as a nav bar drop down no longer works.

The app is not that far along, and I can restart the build to resolve the issue. But I am trying work out where I should look when there are problems in the asset pipeline, for future reference.

I have checked the following places, and they all look ok:

- Gemfile
- application.js
- bootstrap.js.coffee
- application.css
- bootstrap_and_overrides.css.ls
- application.html.erb

I have also tried the following commands:

```
$ rake assets:precompile
$ rake assets:clean
```

And of course I have tried bouncing the web server and clearing the browser cache. The application is on **dev** only.

When there is a asset problem or conflict, **what is the best way to troubleshoot it?** Should I be using Firebug or the like to help identify the actual issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is a broad question, and bugs with asset related items can come from various sources, your first line of attack should be Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, since these can be used to inspect exactly what assets have loaded and if there are any issues with them. Whatever caused bug, you are currently having trouble with the assets themselves, so they are the first thing that should be inspected.

A couple of more specific items in this regard would be looking to see if there are any Javascript errors (using the dev tools Console tab), and also seeing what assets have loaded (using the dev tools network tab). Once you can identify what's wrong with your assets, you can then move a step backward to see why your assets haven't loaded, or loaded incorrectly.

Comment: Nice answer...thanks. Do you know of any "step through" guides for this kind of thing? There do seem to be many places it can go wrong.

Comment: Sorry, not offhand. You're right that these things can be awfully tricky to debug.

Comment: Exactly my point. A methodological guide would be really great.